# How to modify a Perl variable in a different package

Tags: perl, module

I have this

main.pl

```
use Second;

sub main {
    our $var = 0;
    subroutine()
}
```

Second.pm

```
Package Second;

use Exporter;

our @ISA=qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT=qw(subroutine);

use strict;

our $var;
sub subroutine{
    print $var;
}
```

which gives the error

> Use of uninitialized value in print at

How can I send that variable without like parameter?

Answer (score 2):

The code in `main.pl` doesn't have a `package` statement, so every package identifier is in the `main` package by default. That means `our $var=0` is setting the variable `$main::var` to zero, and is nothing to do with the variable `$Second::var` in the module file

The obvious way to fix this is to fully-qualify the variable identifier in `main.pl`, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Second;

$Second::var = 0;
subroutine()
```

Note that you have a capital `P` in `Package` in `Second.pm` that shouldn't be there. Also, it is best to import the `import` subroutine from `Exporter` instead of subclassing it; and a module should always return a *true* value when it is compiled. The file should look like this

```
package Second;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT = qw(subroutine);

our $var;

sub subroutine {
    print $var;
}

1;
```

Comment: Better still is `use Exporter 5.57 'import'; # exported import method`, just in case somebody runs your code on an old Perl.  Exporter didn't support exporting its `import` method into your package until version 5.57.

Comment: this is a small example .. i want that variable to be in global because i need in all packages .. i have many packages